# Box-shadow's 3rd value dramatically decreases page rendering

Tags: css

Using the box-shadow property in Chrome or Firefox, if the 3rd input is a large number, it nearly freezes the browser in Chrome and it slows down Firefox. Is this a bug?

-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 400px #446b6b;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 400px #446b6b;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it is: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22102

I believe it's been patched and should be available soon :-)

Workarounds include: less shadow or use a png for the shadow..

The problem is they're not caching the shadow so it's getting redrawn whenever you scroll..